# Plotting an equation in tikzpicture using pgfplots won't work

Tags: pgfplots

I want to plot this equation: 0.0172x + 2.9971 in lateX using the pgfplots package. I already made an axis and I plotted another graph using data points from a datafile. The data points and respective fit are drawn in the coordinate system, but the equation is not drawn. Help would be appreciated!!

I used this piece of code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]

\caption{Plot of different electric potentials measured at the different PH's of the calibration solutions. A linear fit for all points is shown in blue. The green line is a fit for PH range 5,8-6,8 and the red line a fit for PH range 6,8-7,8}

\begin{flushleft}

\begin{tikzpicture}[] 

    \begin{axis}[
    title={\large{Electric potential at different PH's for other groups}},
    height={100 mm},
    width={150 mm},
    xlabel={PH [Without unit]},
    ylabel={Electric potential [mV]},
    xmin=0, xmax=14,
    ymin=50, ymax=300,
    xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14},
    ytick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180,190,200,210,220,230,240,250,260,270},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    xmajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    ]

\addplot[only marks] file {PHMeasuredata.txt};

\addplot + gnuplot [raw gnuplot, id=AlternativePlot, mark=smooth, draw=red]{
    f(x) = a*x+b;
    a=20;
    b=30;
    fit f(x) "AlternativePlot.txt" using 1:2 via a, b;
    plot [x=0:14] f(x);};

\addplot[no markers, blue]{0.0172*x + 2.9971};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{flushleft}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't considered what kind of values the expression `0.0172*x + 2.9971` will give you for `x` in the range `[0,14]` -- they will be between 2.9971 and about 3.24. But you have set `ymin=50`, meaning that the line is far outside the region you're plotting.

I don't have your datafile of course, but If I remove those plots, and the `ymin`, `ymax` and `ytick` settings in the axis, I get something like this:

[image]

The reason it stops at 5 is that the default domain is `-5:5`, so you want to add `domain=0:14` or similar to the `\addplot` options.

Some other notes:

- `\large` is not a command that takes an argument, it should be used as `{\large text}` not `\large{text}`.
- I don't know your setup, but at least in a default `article` 15cm is far too wide for the text block. You can set the width to `\textwidth` though.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]

\caption{Plot of different electric potentials measured at the different PH's of the calibration solutions. A linear fit for all points is shown in blue. The green line is a fit for PH range 5,8-6,8 and the red line a fit for PH range 6,8-7,8}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    title={\large Electric potential at different PH's for other groups},
    height={80 mm},
    width={\textwidth},
    xlabel={PH [Without unit]},
    ylabel={Electric potential [mV]},
    xmin=0, xmax=14,
%    ymin=50, ymax=300,
    xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14},
%    ytick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180,190,200,210,220,230,240,250,260,270},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    xmajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    ]

%\addplot[only marks] file {PHMeasuredata.txt};

%\addplot + gnuplot [raw gnuplot, id=AlternativePlot, mark=smooth, draw=red]{
%    f(x) = a*x+b;
%    a=20;
%    b=30;
%    fit f(x) "AlternativePlot.txt" using 1:2 via a, b;
 %   plot [x=0:14] f(x);};

\addplot[blue,domain=0:14]{0.0172*x + 2.9971};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```